# improve the performance of regex in javascript for test against whole string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which test for an pattern like key = value and key1 = value1.
It goes  `/^(?:(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{0,}(?:=|>|<|>=|<=|!=)\s{0,}(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{1,}(?:AND|OR)\s{1,})+(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{0,}(?:=|>|<|>=|<=|!=)\s{0,}(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{0,}$|(?:^(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{0,}(?:=|>|<|>=|<=|!=)\s{0,}(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+\s{0,}$)|(?:^\s{0,}$)/`.

Now this is functionally correct but very slow after 20-25 characters and takes around 30 seconds to evaluate. What can be improved here.

I understand that this is not a very specific question but still one which requires inputs..

Comment: That's a bit long, maybe describe in words what exactly you're trying to match? You can replace `{1,}` with `+`, and `{0,}` with `*`

Comment: A string in the form of key value pairs separated by boolean operands

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to match here, but I'd say it's a good bet that it's a mistake trying to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish with a single regex. The best bet to speed things up is to break the problem up, perhaps with some kind of state machine.

Comment: Hi, could you add some information about what you are trying to match and what you are not ? Ex: does `key1 = value2` matches ?

Comment: Regexes are good for many things, but not everything  That regex looks like a mess.. You are probably better of by doing a single for-loop an iterate over the characters in the string, and keep track of the state you are in. That makes it easier to understand what your are trying to do, and will run much faster,

Comment: @Nicolas yes .. 1) a=b 2) a=b AND c=d 3) a=b AND c=d AND e=f and more

Comment: @some is right - this isn't a job for a regex alone. You need to parse the string which you could do in parts with a regex, if you want, which will mean a vastly simpler regex then.

Comment: Could you please add case where you regex is working. Or create a regex101 with the cases you want your regex to match ?

Comment: I've created a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGEAt5/1), it seems working fine and fast.

Comment: Looking at your regexp it looks like you want to match a key that are than be unquoted, quoted with single or double quotes, followed by =, >, <, >=, <= or != and then a value that is either unquoted, quoted by single or double quotes, and then maybe followed by the word AND or OR. That whole part could be repeated multiple times, ending with the same but without AND or OR. Are you trying to parse the string or just verifying it?

Comment: @some just validating and yes thats what is being achieved

Comment: [A simplified version](https://regex101.com/r/AGEAt5/2).

Comment: @Toto the problem is that when you try it in the editor, you will see that if the expression is not correct, it times out and that is a problem...

Comment: Please, edit your question and give some examples.

Comment: @Toto the examples you have in your test cases are quite comprehensive and pretty much cover it.

Comment: @Toto can you explain the optimizations done on the simplified version.. looks ok to me

Comment: I'd split the string at `AND|OR` and filter the result array by [a more simple pattern](https://regex101.com/r/AGEAt5/5). Try, if [this fiddle would speed things up](https://jsfiddle.net/9cwtrbky/).

Comment: All `\w+` occurrences must be replaced with `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is these:

```
(?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")+
```

A lot of regex engines will try many possible matches for `\w+` inside the overall `+` when matching fails. Replacing `\w+` with `\w` should improve performance.

Also, your regex has a structure like:

```
^(TERM (AND|OR) )+TERM$|^TERM$|^$
```

which can be simplified to

```
^(TERM (AND|OR) )*TERM$|^$
```

It might be helpful to construct it like that explicitly (good name choices up to you):

```
const FOO = /(?:\w|'[\w\s]+'|"[\w\s]+")/.source;
const COMPARE = /(?:=|>|<|>=|<=|!=)/.source;
const BAR = String.raw`(?:${FOO}+\s*${COMPARE}\s*${FOO}+)`;
const BAZ = String.raw`^(?:${BAR}\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+)*${BAR}\s*$|^\s*$`;
```

Comment: Cleaver usage of [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) but that raw... Oh...  That [raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) was new to me. Finally a way to write readable complex regular expressions in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version. It uses the schema provided by Ry, except I've remove the quantifier on keys and values.

```
^
  # key 
  (?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")
  # operator
  \s*
  (?:[=><]|[><!]=)
  \s*
  # value
  (?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")
  # 0 or more Boolean operator, key operator value
  (?:
    \s+(?:AND|OR)\s+
    (?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")
    \s*
    (?:[=><]|[><!]=)
    \s*
    (?:'[\w\s]+'|\w+|"[\w\s]+")
  )*
  \s*
$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGEAt5/4)

Comment: I tried using chrome for running it and its still slow.

Comment: yes firefox also slows down. looks to me that regex is not a solution here. you can try in jsfiddle to see this.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex becomes slow because it will do a lot of backtracking before it can conclude there is no match.

I would add a bit of JavaScript in the process, so that you not only get whether the format is correct or not, but also the tokenised version in case it is correct. That output could then also have the wrapping quotes removed:

```js
// Returns array of tokens when given string has valid format, otherwise: undefined
function parse(s) {
    let regex = /(["'])(.+?)\1|((AND|OR)|(\w+))|(!=|<=?|>=?|=)|\S/gi;
    let result = [];
    if (!s.trim().length) return result; // boundary case: empty input

    function nextToken(i, j) { 
        let match = regex.exec(s);
        // Arguments i[, j] define which capture group(s) should be scanned for a value 
        match = match && (match[i] || match[j]);
        return match && result.push(match);
    }
    
    const logical = () => nextToken(4); // AND or OR
    const value = () => nextToken(2, 3); // quoted or unquoted non-empty string
    const comparator = () => nextToken(6); // <, <=, =, !=, >=, >
    const comparison = () => value() && comparator() && value();

    do {
        if (!comparison()) return; // invalid format
    } while (logical());

    return regex.lastIndex ? undefined : result; // ok if at end of input
}

// Example call:
let res = parse(`"a key" = "it's value" AND '100-1' <= 99 OR what=that   `);
console.log(res);
```